# Fiddler Failed to read HTTP request from new client socket

Tags: fiddler

I use Apache common HttpClient to send a request, and want to use fidder moniter the process. following is my setting:

```
    Object myHost = "127.0.0.1";
    sysProperties.put("socksProxyHost", myHost);

    Object myPort = "8888";
    sysProperties.put("socksProxyPort", myPort);
```

But fiddler show me a logs:

10:44:16:6236 [Fiddler] Failed to read HTTP request from (javaw:1408) new client socket, port 49784. 
10:45:17:1321 [Fiddler] Failed to read HTTP request from (javaw:1408) new client socket, port 49785. 
10:46:17:6395 [Fiddler] Failed to read HTTP request from (javaw:1408) new client socket, port 49802. 
10:47:18:1460 [Fiddler] Failed to read HTTP request from (javaw:1408) new client socket, port 49811.

Answer (score 0):

Fiddler isn't a SOCKS proxy, so when you try to use it as one, you'll find that it doesn't work.